# Improve this snippet from a prototype class

Tags: javascript, class, refactoring, prototypejs

This is a snippet from a prototype class i am putting together. The scoping workaround feels a little hacky to me, can it be improved or done differently?

```
var myClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {
        $('formid').getElements().each(function(el){
            $(el).observe("blur", function(){
                this.validateEl(el);
            }.bind(this,el));
        },this);
     },
    validateEl: function(el){
      // validate $(el) in here...
    }
});
```

Also, it seems to me that i could be doing something like this for the event observers:

```
$('formid').getElements().invoke("observe","blur" ...
```

Not sure how i would pass the element references in though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed simplify that a fair bit:

```
var myClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;

        // To demo that we keep the instance reference, set a
        // property on the instance
        this.message = "Hi there";

        $('formid').getElements().invoke("observe", "blur", blurHandler);

        function blurHandler() {
            // `self` references our instance
            // `this` references the element we're observing
            self.validateEl(this);
        }
    },
    validateEl: function(el){

        // validate $(el) in here...

        // note that because of the way we called it, within this function,
        // `this` references the instance, so for instance:
        this.foo(); // alerts "Hi there!"
    },
    foo: function() {
        alert(this.message);
    }
});
```

That uses `invoke` (as you suggested) and a named function for the handler (doesn't have to be named, but I find that it's very helpful to have your functions have names). The handler is a closure. In the `initialize` function, I use a variable to point to `this` because the variable will then be available to the closure. (I called it `self` because that's a standard practice when aliasing `this` for this reason.) The handler makes use of Prototype's native functionality of setting `this` within an event handler to the element being observed. When we call `validateEl` via the closure's `self` reference, we're calling it as a member function as per normal, so within `validateEl`, `this` refers to the instance.

Speaking of named functions, your `initialize` and `validateEl` functions are both anonymous, which means on call stacks and such in debuggers, you'll just see "(?)" rather than a nice, handy name. I always recommend actual named functions; [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).

Comment: thanks for the info on named functions, that's well worth considering. In your example though i presumably would have scope issues if i needed to call another function from within the class within the validateEl function unless i first declared `self` outside the class

Comment: @seengee: No, you could do that with standard `this.foo` notation. Within `validateEl`, `this` will refer to the instance, because of the way we called it. When you make a function call via a property, as with `self.validateEl(...)`, it means "call `validateEl` and make `this` within the call equal to `self`". More here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html

Comment: @TJ - wow, thanks for all the detail. some really good information in there

Comment: @TJ - I may well use the other approach but i have learned a great deal from your answer so points to you :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see nothing wrong with your code :)

About observers you can to something like this:

```
$('formid').getElements().invoke("observe","blur", function(e) {
    this.validateEl(e.element());
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Although it works, using `event.element` here is a lot more work than is required. Also, although you're safe with `blur` (because it doesn't bubble), you wouldn't want to do that with `click` or any event that *does* bubble, because `event.element` would return the bottommost element (which could be a `span`, an `em`, an `a`, etc.) that was clicked, *not* the element you're observing. Sometimes that's what you want, sometimes not.

Comment: @TJ - good call on the bubbling - when you say that its more work than required do you mean that purely in comparison to your closure example?

Comment: @seengee: Closure or binding. But unless it's happening *a lot*, it doesn't really matter regardless. It's just that `event.element` does a couple of extra function calls you don't need if you can go direct, but we're talking a couple of calls vs. one or none, which compared to everything else happening around the event probably doesn't really matter. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it will look slightly less verbose if you create a `registerBlur` method:

```
var myClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {
        $('formid').getElements().each(this.registerBlur, this);
    },
    registerBlur: function(el) {
        Event.observe(el, 'blur', this.validateEl.bind(this, el));
    },
    validateEl: function(el){
      // validate $(el) in here...
    }
});
```

But I agree with Rui Carneiro, I don't see anything wrong with your code either.